# MySQL VARCHAR field or PHP substr

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, varchar, substr

I have a user registration form using PHP & MySQL & jQuery.
What is the best way to limit user input to 120 chars.

1st) Using a field type like VARCHAR with 120 chars (length) and let the MySQL do the "dirty" job.
 
2nd) Using PHP `substr`.

or sth else...

Always having in mind:

1) Performance - Resources usage
2) Efficient
3) Safety - Vulnerabilities

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For user comprehension : Limit in the GUI

For safety from data you receive : Limit in Php.

For safety from other programmers : Limit in SQL

Comment: Limit in GUI can be done with the (non-standard, but fully functional) `maxlength`-attribute.

Comment: For user friendliness, have PHP issue a warning if somehow >120 chars are submitted, to let the user know that their data's being truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Both:

- limit the field in HTML/PHP
- limit the size of the field/column in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

1) Maxlength on imput field
2) Validation with JS
3) Validation with PHP

If size is over 120 return error. Store only if text length is correct.